# Read int and char from the same file in C

Tags: c, file, input

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
i 3755
i 3633
i 4435
i 1434
```

how would I go about reading this as an input, I've tried using fscanf, but it keeps on giving me a random character after the 'i'

for example output would look like

> i% 3755
>
> i5 3633

etc.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
    int data = 0; 
char command; 
if(fptr==NULL)
    printf("File Cannot Be Read"); 

fscanf(fptr,"%c %d\n", &command, &data); 
printf("%c " , command);
printf("%d\n" , data);

fscanf(fptr,"%s %d\n", &command, &data); 
printf("%c " , command);
printf("%d\n" , data); 

fscanf(fptr,"%s %d\n", &command, &data); 
printf("%s " , command);
printf("%d\n" , data);
```

none of them seem to work. Thanks for your help in advance!

edit: Heres the working code for anybody that was having the same problem:

```
int data = 0; 
char command; 
fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 

if(fptr==NULL)
    printf("File Cannot Be Read"); 

while(fscanf(fptr,"%c %d \n", &command, &data) == 2)
{

        if(command == 'i')
        {
            printf("insert found\n");
        }
            if(command == 'd')
        {
            printf("delete found\n");
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d", command, &data);
```

should be:

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d", &command, &data); 
getchar();  // consume the newline character that fscanf left.
```

Assuming you defined:

```
char command;
int data;
```

Comment: ah the getchar() command is what I was missing definitely, but how come I have to push enter for my program to get the next line??

Comment: ohhhh i got it, to work without the getchar() by removing the \n from fscanf(fptr,"%s %d\n", &command, &data); 
will be putting it in a loop of course. Thanks a lot for your help everybody

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I would recommend you to, in a loop, read a line using `fgets()` and then use `strtok()` to get different 'strings' and then cast according to your parsing methodology. But Mike is right as well, you can use `fscanf(fptr, "%c %d\n", &command, &data)` to read. When you're using a string, you can ignore the usage of "`&`" before the variable name. But when its a character or an integer or a float.. you will need to use the address of operator("`&`")

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect and will result in a buffer overrun:

```
fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", &command, &data);
```

as `command` has only enough space for a single `char` but `fscanf()` with format specifier `"%s"` will read until next whitespace and then write a terminating null character into `command`. Use a `char[]` to read and restrict the number of `char`s to be read.

Note that the `NULL` check just prints an error message, it does not actually prevent use of a `NULL` file pointer.

---

To ensure that each line is of the correct format use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a line and then use [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read the fields. If `fscanf()` is used to read directly from the file then these *two* lines:

```
i
3755
```

are treated identically to the *single* line:

```
i 3755
```

as a new-line character is also whitespace.
Example:

```
if (fptr)
{
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, fptr))
    {
        char command;
        int data;
        if (2 == sscanf(line, "%c %d", &command, &data))
        {
            /* Use 'command' and 'data'. */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

at this line :

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d", command, &data);
```

you should give it a pointer to command. like this :

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d", &command, &data);
```

the next line can't work because the reading cursor is already at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

in your `fscanf` function you have to expect the return to line by adding space at the end of format. Like this

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d ", &command, &data);
```

The space character replaces return to new line, tabulation and spaces

BTW I see that you use `%s` to read a char `&command` and this is incorrect

```
fscanf(fptr,"%s %d\n", &command, &data);
```

you have to use this instead

```
fscanf(fptr,"%c %d ", &command, &data);
```